# Magento 2: Edit data-mage-init attribute from body tag

Tags: magento2, attributes, xml, data-mage-init

I am trying to edit the data-mage-init attribute from the Magento 2 body element. I am optimizing page load and this attribute is passing a gif file that is not needed.

I tried to remove it with:

```
<body>
   <attribute name="data-mage-init" value="">
</body>
```

I could add attributes with this code but not remove any..

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately need to override [root.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml) or init your script via script tag somewhere else.